# How to make a UIImage Scrollable inside a UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uiimage

I currently have a `ScrollView` and inside the `ScrollView` i have a `UIImageView`.

I get different image sizes from my server and most images are larger than the `bounds` of my screen.

I would like to scroll through the image if it is bigger than my screen.

Something like this....

[image: enter link description here]

This is what i have tried so far.

```
let image = UIImage(named: "myImg")
let heightInPoints = image?.size.height
let heightInPixels = heightInPoints ?? 0 * image!.scale
let widthInPoints = image?.size.width
let widthInPixels = widthInPoints ?? 0 * image!.scale

self.imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: widthInPixels, height: heightInPixels) //= image
self.imageView.image = image

scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: imageView.frame.width, height: imageView.frame.height)
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Either it only scrolls vertically or horizontally or it never scrolls.

What am I doing wrong. Or is there a better approach to get this effect ?

Comment: Try to look this article [Look here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/560-uiscrollview-tutorial-getting-started) it contains helpful information about your implementation

Comment: @MertalpTasdelen This is not exactly what i am looking for. I don't want to zoom the image .... I want to calculate its frame size and make the imageview the same size and then add it to the scrollview so that i can scroll through it in all directions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solution 1. Updating Frames

Firstly, make sure the views hierarchy is correctly setup (the `imageView` is added to the `scrollView`):

```swift
scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
```

Then I'd suggest rewriting this code as something like:

```swift
let image = UIImage(named: "myImg")
imageView.image = image                        // setup image to imageView
imageView.frame.size = image?.size ?? .zero    // setup image size or zero to imageView
scrollView.contentSize = image.size ?? .zero   // setup image size or zero as a content size
```

## Solution 2. Using constraints

There is also another solution using constraints instead of manually setting up the sizes. This takes a bit more code but doesn't require sizes recomputing when you change the image.

```swift
scrollView.addSubview(imageView)                            // Setup the views hierarchy
imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false // Make sure constraints won't interfere with autoresizing mask
NSLayoutConstraint.activate(
    [
        imageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leftAnchor),    // attaching to the left
        imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor),      // attaching to the top
        imageView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.rightAnchor),  // attaching to the right
        imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor) // attaching to the bottom
    ]
)
```

Then we replace existing image with a new one like this:

```swift
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "myImg")
```

Both approaches work for me in Playground. So, if these still won't work for you, please share more information about how you set up the hierarchy and additional parameters of the scroll view.

Comment: Hey Denis your `Solution 1. Updating Frames` worked for me so i will accept this answer. But ultimately since i was using autolayouts, i figured out a way to get the same effect using autolayouts. I am also scaling the image according to its height and width to fit the screen perfectly. So with your approach i was having some issues with scaling but for the question i asked, this was the right solution. Thanks.